# How can I read this csv data?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting an error:

> Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 88, saw 4

while trying to read this data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/blob/master/public/data/vaccinations/vaccinations.csv')
data = df.head()
```

I've tried with sep = ";" etc but it doesn't help. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: As Osian already pointed out in his answer, your link does not point to the (raw) `csv` file. Regarding your confusion with `;` as a separator, this particular `csv` file is a comma-separated file. I assume you are living in a German-speaking region where a semicolon was often used as a separator in the past (or still is?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that you are pulling in the GitHub UI and not the csv with your link

```
https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/blob/master/public/data/vaccinations/vaccinations.csv
```

Try this as this is the raw csv:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/vaccinations/vaccinations.csv
```

Further as Thomas said, a CSV is a comma, as in (`,`) separated file - not a semicolon (`;`).

Comment: OMG didn't see that. Big thanks!

Comment: If it helped, please mark it as correct by clicking the checkmark